# Can I create deterministic data with webauthn authentication

Tags: credentials, navigator, webauthn

I have an application that works with a private key. This private key is kept encrypted with the password determined by the user on the server side in order not to cause any difficulties to the user. When the user wants to use the private key, user can decrypt it with their password and use it again. After the private key is decrypted with a password, I check if any meaningful data is revealed.
[You can check process graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiZTG.png)

I want to remove the password here and integrate webauthn instead. However, it is very difficult to make changes in the system because the code base of the application is very large. Is there a deterministic data that I can use instead of the password here from the values that come with the authentication response? Would it be possible to design this structure?
[Thats what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK7hB.png)

I know that Webauthn is not an emerging standard for storing a data. But I am wondering if I can create a deterministic data that cannot be obtained outside of authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PRF extension](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#prf-extension) in recent versions of Chromium-based browsers, and with CTAP2-capable security keys, to get a symmetric key from a security key assertion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked it, but I cannot enable it. I tried it in Canary browser also. I read https://blog.millerti.me/2023/01/22/encrypting-data-in-the-browser-using-webauthn/ this article. He says if prf return false, you should try another security key until you find one that works. But dont understand what that means.

Comment: What make and model of security key are you trying? (Yubikey series 5 should work, for example.)